# How can I have both onecolumn and twocolumn in the same page in ACM SIGPLAN paper

Tags: two-column, acm

I need to have in the same page both onecolumn and twocolumn. As default, a page in ACM SIGPLAN latex is twocolumn. But I have a picture that need to be located in onecolumn. When I use :
\onecolumn
here picture
\twocolumn
...
My image will be put in a seprate page (alone). But I don't put it in a seprate page. I wonder if I have in the same page both onecolumn and twocolumn, i.e have that image at the top of the page in onecolumn, and the rest of that page contains ordinary text in two columnn.

Is it possible?
SIGPLAN latex: http://drupal.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/sigplanconf-guide.pdf

Comment: It would be great if you could post a small mock-up of a document in the `sigplanconf` document class using [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) and perhaps some images from [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) so that community members have something to work with. It will speed up the search for solution, surely.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the trick might be to use the `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}` environment. That should give you a figure that spans the whole page width, while allowing the rest of that page to be in two columns. In contrast, the `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` environment gives you a figure that spans only one column.

Comment: This is, i think, so much sought after and so little found ;) thanks for this! and, ACM could have documentation about this. kind of stupid that they have not, or that it's hard to find (at least)